# Create Bundle from 3rd party

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

Looking around I found nothing that addresses my issue so here goes.

I have a 3rd party library I will to use Symfony2, It has it's own Auto Loader and the project of structured into something like this

```
-project
   - Classes
      - Actions
   - Library
      - Package Name
         - Actions
         - Connection
```

The project is namespaced.

My question is should I

```
a- re-write this into a Bundle (In-house)
b- add this to the Vendors directory and create a wrapper for this
```

If option a would you also point me on how to structure the app for Symfony, Or if option b do I use their Auto Loader or Symfonys?

Thanks for any help on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

definitely B.

Include the vendor library just like all other vendors and then create your own bundle that will "bridge" any symfony-specific functionality (if there is any). If they have an autoloader then it should be fine to use that.

Comment: so just add it to the AppKernel ( kinda like twig ), correct? Is there some official documentation on this?

Comment: I don't know of any documentation, but all the KNP bundles do this. The MenuBundle is the symfony-specific parts of the more generic knp-menu component. Is there a reason you need it in a bundle as opposed to just using the vendor lib directly?

Comment: Might be fun to refactor into something but right now I need working